# Scala: Modelling using an object, a case class, and a listMap

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I want to define my return type for a function, something like:

```
def getMovieInformation (name: String): Information = ???
```

Then of course I need something like:

```
case class Information (name: String, inTheathers: Boolean)
```

So far, so good. But now I want to get information from an internal API, 
that gives me an advance result, which normal user cannot understand so I want to use a `mapList` of `String` to `String` to return a more general info, something like:

```
val qualityFeedback =  ListMap(
  "advance info" -> "Movie has a great quality",
  "another advance info " -> "Movie has a bad quality"
)
```

Then my case class will be something like:

```
case class Information (name: String, inTheathers: Boolean, qualityFeedback: String)
```

Ok now if I want to put everything together, I will have:

```
object Movie {
  case class Information (name: String, inTheathers: Boolean, qualityFeedback: String)

  val qualityFeedback =  ListMap("advance info" -> "Movie has a great quality","another advance info " -> "Movie has a bad quality")
}
```

And in another class, I will import the `Movie` object, and will have:

```
def getMovieInformation (movieName: String) : Information = {
   //Call internal API and get the advance value match it with the list map above and get an explanatory string. 
   val feedback = ???  

   val isInTheather: Boolean = ???  

   //Need to return Movie.Information
   val information: Movie.Information = (name = movieName, inTheater = isInTheater, qualityFeedback = feedback)  

   Ok(views.html.movie(information)) 
}
```

I don' t like the above code; even though semantically it is correct. Simply because I have `Movie.Information`. I  also do not want to bring out the case class because I want to package it with the `qualityFeedback` within an object.

Is there a better/cleaner way to model this? Or rather how I can model this in a functional manner (without using object and case class).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're not liking here? The style of method composition?

Comment: Is there any relation between `Information` and `MovieInformation` case classes?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yes the dot notation and then two upper camel case looks odd to me.

Comment: @PuneethReddyV thanks for the question, updated the answer, they are the same, because didnt want to have `Movie.MovieInformation`.

Comment: Could the upvoters please explain what is so "clear and useful" about this question? Honesly, I'm rather tempted to VtC as "Unclear". The code snippets do not look compilable. Something is said about an unknown method `mapList`, then `qualityFeedback: ListMap` is defined, then all of a sudden it's again `qualityFeedback: String`... I don't understand anything, sorry. @DaveRose I think it would be helpful if you provided an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with input, expected output, and a clear description of what goes wrong. In any case, `[Information]` is not a valid return type

Comment: Furthermore: there is nothing odd about the `Movie.Information` notation, because the dot `.` is used not only for *methods*, but for accessing *members* in general. If the member happens to be a type, then so be it: use `.` to access the member, then use upper case to write down the type name. Nothing strange about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not like `Movie.Information` in your code you just need to `import Movie._`.

```
import Movie._
def getMovieInformation (name: String) : Information = {
   //Call internal API and get the value based on the key from   Movie.qualityFeedback
   //Now just return Information
}
```

Classes defined inside objects in Scala are almost the same as static classes inside classes in Java. You would have the extra `Movie.` in both languages unless you import (or static import in java).